# Why do Rustc and Clang's target-triple have 4 components

Tags: rust, clang

The [target-triple](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CrossCompilation.html#target-triple) in Rustc/Clang to choose compilation target has *4* components:

```
<arch><sub>-<vendor>-<sys>-<abi>
```

Why is it called a target-*triple* then?

Comment: I don't think this pattern was created by clang or rustc: https://wiki.osdev.org/Target_Triplet

Comment: In GNU land, it's explicitly a three-element triplet, where the last element might happen to include a dash in it. The pattern is `cpu-vendor-os`, where `os` might just happen to be `kernel-system`. It isn't exactly standardized. See https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.68/html_node/Specifying-Target-Triplets.html

Comment: What you're listing is really 5 components, but as @kmdreko's link shows there are 3 broad categories: the machine, the vendor, and the OS ABI.